# What flying machine is this model?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Help with this flying machine. I think it is a concept / prototype designed in Europe in the nineteenth century.

[image]

Comment: Leonardo daVinci?

Answer (score 9):

A friend sent me this. Thanks for the answers.

Gull-wing by Werner Siemens, Germany 1847.

[image: Gull-wing by Werner Siemens, Germany 1847]

Comment: Yes, I have another source for that sketch by Siemens [Rockets, Missiles and Men in Space, Willy Ley. Signet Books, New American Library, 1969] https://imgur.com/4jY8II3  https://imgur.com/aCiwhis

Answer (score 4):

It may be the  "la barque ailée" as exposed in the Bourget [air museum](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:La-Barque-ailee-de-Jean-Marie_Le_Bris_Musee_du_Bourget_P1010397.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an imitation of Leonardo da Vinci's flying machine. As you can see from the following picture
[image]